# Configure kubernetes to DNS resolve the given domain as the first try, instead of using given-domain.namespace.svc.cluster.local

Tags: linux, kubernetes, dns, azure-aks

By default, when we raise a request from a Pod to another pod, Kubernetes is trying to append `.namespace.svc.cluster.local` to the domain we gave and try to resolve.

But in our case, we are already using a fully qualified URL to raise the request (http://service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local/api/...) in all the places, but here also Kubernetes will try to resolve DNS for `service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local.namespace.svc.cluster.local` and try a bunch of other domains as well, at last only it will try the actually given domain.

**Question:** Is there a way to configure Kubernetes to use the given domain for DNS resolve on the first try? If failed then it can try other domains

**Environment Info:**

Environment: AKS
Pod OS: Debian GNU v10 (buster)

**Additional Info:**

Contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` inside a Pod

```
search namespance.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local reddog.microsoft.com
nameserver x.x.x.x
options ndots:5
```

Wireshark:

[image]
As you can see, for every single successful request, there are 4 failed request before it.

Comment: Have you tried `ndots:0` or `ndots:1` ?

Comment: @Philippe Does changing this will affect other behaviors? For example: If it can't resolve with the domain that I provided then it must fall back to appending `namespance.svc.cluster.local` and retry it

Comment: Yes, it will fall back to appending namespance.svc.cluster.local...

Comment: @Philippe Nice, Is there a way to configure it to all pods at once instead of doing it pod by pod. Currently, we don't have any pod specific config/ymal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lowering the `ndots` will fix the issue

> ndots: sets a threshold for the number of dots which must appear in a name before an initial absolute query will be made. The default for n is 1, meaning that if there are any dots in a name, the name will be tried first as an absolute name before any search list elements are appended to it.

Try this :

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: ...
      image: ...
  dnsConfig:
    options:
      - name: ndots
        value: "1"
```